# function doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I need a little help with this function:

```
function  passar() {  
    var fotos1 = document.getElementById("foto1");
    var fotos2 = document.getElementById("foto2");
    var fotos3 = document.getElementById("foto3");

    if ( fotos1.style.display = "block" ) {   
        fotos1.style.display = "none";  
        fotos2.style.display = "block";  
    } else if ( fotos2.style.display = "block" ) {  
        fotos2.style.display = "none";  
    }  
}
```

It was supposed to hide "fotos 2" when the first condition is changed but it didn't work, someone knows why?

Comment: i'm kind of upset that not a single person has said to use the identity operator `===` ...

Comment: `==` and `!=` is one of the main reasons that the code quality of javascript is as low as it is... use `===` and `!==` instead.

Comment: I was the only one that gave the answer using `===` and no one cares. :)

Answer (score 3):

`=` for assignment

`==` for comparison

`===` for strict comparison

```
if (fotos1.style.display === "block") {   
fotos1.style.display = "none";  
fotos2.style.display = "block";  
 } else if (fotos1.style.display === "none") {  
 fotos2.style.display = "none";    
  }  
}
```

Comment: Other languages have `===` too :-P

Answer (score 1):

Your conditional statement is doing an assignment rather than a comparison:

```
if (fotos1.style.display === "block") {   
    fotos1.style.display = "none";  
    fotos2.style.display = "block";  
} else if (fotos1.style.display === "none") {  
    fotos2.style.display = "block";    
}
```

Also, it is recommended to use strict comparison using `===` over the weak comparison `==`. You get the added benefit of the comparison also being roughly 4X faster in some browsers.

Comment: Didn't realize it was that much faster.  Cool.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a comparison operator which is double equals in this case:

```
if (fotos1.style.display == "block") {
```

Instead you are using a single equals which is an assignment parameter:

```
if (fotos1.style.display = "block") {
```

Comment: Can i know why was this given minus 1?