# Broken If/Else Statement using Randomizer

Tags: javascript

Ok, I'm still a beginner at JavaScript, but I'm trying to write a rock-paper-scissors type game. Everything is working pretty well, except that every time that I run the "reload" function the output is whatever is the *first* "if" statement of the *second* if/else statement. By this I mean that the output "Both sides reload." would come back every time if the code were to be arranged how it is below. Also I already know that the randomizer works. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
var reload = function() {
var random = function() {
var randomizer = Math.random() * 100

if (randomizer <= 33) {
var compDecision = 1
}
else if (randomizer > 67) {
var compDecision = 2
}
else if (33 < randomizer && randomizer <= 67) {
var compDecision = 3
}}

if (compDecision = 1) {
confirm("Both sides reload.")
}

else if (compDecision = 2) {
confirm("You reload and the enemy takes up defensive positions.")
}

else if (compDecision = 3) {
confirm("The enemy takes you out as you reload.")
}}
```

Comment: Start by indenting, if you want to understand the code

Comment: `=` is an assignment operator, not a comparator; possible duplicate of [function doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10746081/710446)

Comment: It's `==` or `===` for comparison not `=`. And you are using a local variable used in another function. You are placing a function inside another function, I'm doubting you want to do that.

Comment: You are never calling `random()` at all? Also`compDecision` is a local variable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all use `=` for assignments, and `==` for logical compare operation.
Then you should declare `var compDecision` as a empty or default `var` and then assign to it a value without using `var` again. I would recommended using semi-colons `;` to end your statements, unlike JavaScript, they are not optional for other languages.
Here is your working code, check the differences conclude the solution:

```
 var reload = function () {

    var compDecision = 0;
    var random2 = function () {
        var randomizer = Math.random() * 100
        if (randomizer <= 33) {
            compDecision = 1;
        } else if (randomizer > 67) {
            compDecision = 2;
        } else  {
            compDecision = 3;
        }
    }
    random2();
    if (compDecision == 1) {
        alert("Both sides reload.");
    } else if (compDecision == 2) {
        alert("You reload and the enemy takes up defensive positions.");
    } else if (compDecision == 3) {
        alert("The enemy takes you out as you reload.");
    }
}

    reload();
```

Tested here : http://jsfiddle.net/urahara/6rtt0w62/

Comment: Your statement about the semi colon isn't true. You don't **have** to have them.

Comment: I know but isn't it overwhelming for someone with this kind of coding problem? It's great to show off,  but why confuse him more? putting `;` won't hurt, but not using them properly may lead to problems.. @Spencer Wieczorek any Polish relatives :) ?

Comment: Having both semi-colons and new lines to end a statement isn't too complex. That being said you can mentioned something like *"I would recommended using semi-colons (`;`) to end your statements, unlike JavaScript, they are not optional for other languages."*.

Comment: @Urahara You don't actually need that `if (33 < randomizer && randomizer <= 67)` as it has exhausted all other possibilities at that point.

Comment: True, I wasn't analysing this much.., thank you for suggestion.